# Stuck in figuring out how to adjust scrollbar position when zooming

Tags: c

I am implementing a zoom feature of a 20x20 grid that also has a 640x480 grid on top, where each made up square is called a resolution. The entire space is for instance 3x3 resolutions (640 * 3) in width and (480 * 3) in height and there is a scrollbar that can scroll over this area.

The first zoom level is 100% and so:
I set the grid size to *2, the resolutions also twice as big and the entire space * 2.

However, I'll also have to re-adjust the scrollbar position so that it remains on the same visual location after the zoom and I am really not that good in math. How do I do that?

---

A diagram:
[image]

*where the visible area should be after zoom

---

Edit: I create this simulator to quickly and easily do real-time simulations:

https://youtu.be/RfiaUXWNjQE

this one works with the following:

`hNew = hCurrent * 2 + resolution.width / 2;`

it obviously works with the first zoom level.

later update:
`hNew = hCurrent * (1 + zoomLevels) + resolution.width / 2;`

appears to be working for every zoom level.

---

The aforementioned approach works, but it can only map from a no-zoomed world to any zoom level rather than from every zoom level to every zoom level.

A better more conventional way is to convert current (before zoom) values of the horizontal/vertical scrollbar to %
then after zoom calculations and resizing get the value of that % of the new world size.

so for horizontal adjustment it would look like this:

```
h% = hValue * 100.0 / hValueMax;
// ...zoom...
hValueNew = h% * hValueNewMax / 100.0;
```

Comment: This really needs code for context. A quick sketch helps us out a lot.

Comment: Does the scroll bar have just one position, or a begin/end pair? In either case, figure out the position *as a percentage or fraction* then multiply that by the new range. Like `oldY / oldH * newH` should do it, assuming the `newY` is scaled based on `oldY` the same way.

Comment: In this case some drawing of your intented grid layout might be useful.

Comment: @Gerhardh I actually did tries this as well, but ended up being even more confused.

Comment: @tadman It just has horizontal scrollbar with values in the range of 0-width
starting from left and a vertical one with the range of 0-height, starting from top

Comment: That's better, but it helps a lot if you can state your objective in terms of code. Give us at least a taste of the situation you're in. For example, a function `int getScrollBarOffset(...)` with some example arguments that match what you're dealing with.

Comment: It sounds like what you need is a [LERP function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation), of which there are many, many examples. The "math" might be a little fussy, but if you know the exact answer you're supposed to get, it's not so bad. You can always hack around until it works out!

Comment: @tadman I rarely get into such situations that I am stuck for so long, I feel like my thinking is not clear and in the right direction. The code is useless, I described what has been doe with code, otherwisem I'd love to post. However, I drew a diagram to help with understanding.

Comment: Basically what tadman said, however it may be worth considering having UI elements not be affected by scale and instead calculate them in "screen space"

Comment: the space is drawn with cairo.

Comment: Ah, so I probably misunderstood. What you're effectively asking is how to position the knob(s) on the scrollbar(s)?

Comment: @vmt Correct, the knobs/sliders. The new positions of what is visible on-screen after zoom.

Comment: Well in that case, let's take the Y-axis for example: The relative position of the top edge of the viewport is at: viewport_y / grid_height. The relative height of the viewport is: viewport_height / grid_height. Scale all values by your zoom factor. The values you get out will be in the normalized range 0...1, and use these values to scale your scrollbar knob and position.

Comment: This works as long as the visible area is at the center (scrollbars h640 v480): `hNew = (hOld + wOld) / 2`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You calculate the horizontal scroll bar separately using the respective values for positions and widths

Comment: @vmt see my update, this should make everything crystal clear.